# How to use single button for two purpose

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I made a component for one Button with animation effect so that i can use it in my other components by simply importing it. I did a lot of code in Button component for animation so i don't want to use a lot of same code again and again in other components.

Is there any way I can use the Button for different events by just importing. For example; In one component I import the **Button** as submitting the user information and in other component i am import the **Button** for displaying user data.

Comment: you can call a function that takes a parameter and you can differenciate what operation to perform according to that parameter variable

Answer (score 2):

Of course! This is the components idea. You mught want to receive a prop in your Button to handle whatever happens onClick.

I.E.

Parent Component
create the especific function to handle

```
function handleClick() { ... }

<YourCustomButton onClick={handleClick} />
```

In YourCustomButton just use this function on event

```
class YourCustomButton extends React......

<Button onClick={this.props.onClick}> ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a props for button to provide an option like

Implement in other component:

```
<custombutton mode={"submitmode"} clickevent={handleBtnClick} />
<custombutton mode={"displaymode"} clickevent={handleBtnClick} />

handleBtnClick=() =>{

if(mode =="submitmode"){
//..do code for submit
}
else if(mode=="displaymode"){
//..do code for display
}
 }
```

Actual button component:

```
class Button extends custombutton{

handleClick =() =>{
this.props.clickevent();
}

render(){
return(
{props.mode=="submitmode" &&
<button type="submit" onClick={handleClick} class="submitstyle" />
}

{props.mode=="displaymode" &&
<button class="displaystyle" onClick={handleClick} />
}

);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course there is, just give it different props:

Example on codesandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-wing-okiqw

The parent:

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hi there</h1>
      <h2>Click on first button to sum 1, click to second button to sum 2!</h2>
      <Fbutton functionality="sumone" />
      <Fbutton functionality="sumtwo" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

You are calling `Fbutton` two times, one with `sumone` another with `sumtwo` props.

The son:

```js
function Fbutton(props) {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const sumone = () => setCount(count + 1);
  const sumtwo = () => setCount(count + 2);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={props.functionality === "sumone" ? sumone : sumtwo}>
        Sum: {count}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

suppose you have a button like `<Button pageName="home" />`

And in that component suppose ,

```
class Button extends Compoenent {



onClick =()=>{
if(this.props.pageName == "home"){
// do your home action
} else if(this.props.pageName == "tab"){

// do your tab action
}
}

render(){
return(
<Button onClick={() => this.onClick()} />
)
}
}
```

Hope thats clear, feel free for doubts